# how to lock a specific file in github repository

Tags: github, next.js, vercel

I have a public project on github and I deploy it on vercel through github.
There is a file there that needs to be there for everything to work.
But I do not want anyone to have access to it except me.
Is it possible to make it private only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make some files private in a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177014/make-some-files-private-in-a-repository)

Comment: no. I have a public repository and I have a config file that must be there.
I want only me to have access to this file

Comment: Do you want to restrict access to certain values contained in that file or to the whole file? If it's just values that you're concerned with, then use environment variables rather than hardcoding them in the file.