# how not to expose whole codebase to a remote developer?

Tags: github, remote-access, github-for-windows

for a small startup , I employed some remote developers. However, I only want to reveal the necessary codes to a certain developer, not the entire source code.

is this kind of feature offered by GitHub? If not, please provide a workaround.

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make some files private in a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177014/make-some-files-private-in-a-repository)

Answer (score -1):

With git repositories in GitHub there is no way to prevent a developer from cloning the whole repository and GitHub can't filter the contents of the repository to leave out part of the data. Permissions in GitHub can only prevent access to a repository, make the whole repo read-only or grant write access to the repository.

If you really want to limit access, you'll need to split your solution into multiple pieces, each in their own git repository. You can then set permissions for each repository in GitHub.

As a developer myself I caution you against this. A developer with only part if the sources would have a hard time verifying their changes work in way you intend to and it might make it much harder for them to debug any issues that happen in development.